# RewriteRule changing the URL instead of mapping to a file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've encounter a weird behavior that I cannot explain nor correct. I need to redirect every `HTTP` request to `HTTPS`. I've use the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# The query string in the rewrite is for testing purposes
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1&%{REQUEST_URI}&http=%{HTTPS} [L]
```

So far, it works. Then, I need a single page to be `HTTP`, so I added some rewrite conditions :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/not-https
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/not-https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1&%{REQUEST_URI}&https=%{HTTPS} [L]
```

Now, here what's happening. For some reasons, when accessing the `/not-https` page, it redirects to `/index.php?url=not-https&/not-https&https=off`

Here is a map of GET requests followed by the redirects / displayed URL.

```
GET: http://example.com/test
  ->  https://example.com/test with proper $_GET

GET: http://example.com/test.jpg
  ->  https://example.com/test.jpg with no $_GET (file exists)

GET: https://example.com/not-https
  ->  http://example.com/not-https
  ->  http://example.com/index.php?url=not-https&/not-https&https=off
```

My question is why does the `not-https` change the displayed URL (and therefor, mess up my application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because value of `REQUEST_URI` variable is changing to `/index.php?...` in last rule that makes condition `!^/non-https` succeed in 2nd rule and makes it execute that rule.

Change your 1st 2 rules to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+not-https [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+not-https [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Unlike `REQUEST_URI` variable `THE_REQUEST` doesn't change it's value after execution of other internal rewrites.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved everything. It was my guess that `REQUEST_URI` was somehow changing, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Plus, I find it very hard to debug `.htaccess` files...